# Enable WinRM for domain user

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, winrm

Is it possible to enable winrm connection for domain user? I have an automation script which uses winrm for connecting to remote machines. The winrm connection does not work with Domain user name and password the way it works with Administrator account. Is there any setting that has to be enabled to have the domain user to have access to the machine via WinRM?

Automation with terraform (vsphere)

Answer (score 3):

There are two methods (of which I am aware) to achieve this.

First (the easiest), you can add the desired accounts to the scope-specific seuciry group "Remote Management Users" group (the domain group if looking to access domain controllers, or the local group if looking to access a member server or workstation).

Alternatively, you can either register a new PS Session Configuration ([Register-PSSessionConfiguration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/register-pssessionconfiguration?view=powershell-6) - a process I will not go into), or modify the ACL of the  existing default PSSessionConfiguration, Microsoft.Powershell, ([Set-PSSessionConfiguration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-pssessionconfiguration?view=powershell-6)).

---

To modify the existing configuration, you can either use the SDDL GUI by running the following:

```
Set-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Microsoft.Powershell -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI
```

This will pop up a familiar Security dialog to modify the ACL.  Depending upon what you are looking to do, you will have to adjust the permissions accordingly.  This will have to be manually repeated on each endpoint.

[image: Permissions Dialog for the PSSession Configuration]

Or, if looking to script the changes to multiple endpoints, you can use an SDDL string.  Depending upon your familiarity with the SDDL syntax, this could prove more challenging, but it will allow you to "deploy" the change easily.

```
Set-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Microsoft.Powershell -SecurityDescriptorSddl "O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GA;;;RM)(A;;GXGR;;;S-1-5-21-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXX)(A;;GA;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)"
```

The above SDDL translates to the default settings (captured in the image above) with an additional entry for an AD object with the Read & Execute permissions.
S-1-5-32-580 is the well known SID for the Remote Management Users Group.

```
  <SCOPE>\Administrators:  Full Control 
  <SCOPE>\S-1-5-32-580:    Full Control 
  <SCOPE>\<Principal>:     Execute (Invoke);Read(Get,Enumerate,Subscribe)
  INTERACTIVE:             Full Control
```

Comment: The domain user I am trying to use for this purpose is already an Administrator. But for some reason when i m trying the domain user with winrm connection i m not able to get through. I have tried giving the Adminsitrator and Remote Management user group Execute permissions, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these link can help.

[How To Enable WinRM with Domain Group Policy for PowerShell Remoting](https://www.kjctech.net/how-to-enable-winrm-with-domain-group-policy-for-powershell-remoting/)